# How to disable application request validation in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to be able to save things like:

`<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/gpub?url=http%3A%2F%2Foj0ijfii34kccq3ioto7mdspc7r2s7o9-ss-opensocial.googleusercontent.com%2Fgadgets%2Fifr%3Fup_title%3DBrands%26up_initialstate%26up__table_query_url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fspreadsheets.google.com%252Fspreadsheet%252Ftq%253Frange%253DA%25253AE%2526key%253D0AqFjLMbUaBn_>`

In an `nvarchar(max)` field, I get the following when I try to insert:

> "Server Error in
>   '/TheScienceAndArtOfDataVisualization'
>   Application. A potentially dangerous
>   Request.Form value was detected from
>   the client
>   `(ctl00$MainContent$txtCode="<script
>   src="https:/...").`"

Comment: I tried to add the validateRequest="false" to the page I want to disable validation in it, it didn't work, I got the same error message! PS: I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET 4.0 you may also have to make a change to web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <!-- Sad requirement to allow ValidateRequest="false" -->
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

But it should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 3):

DeadYCool's answer will work if you want to disable request validation on all pages, if you just want to disable it on a specific page, you can set `ValidateRequest="false"` in the `Page` directive of the .aspx file.

```
<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false"...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try not to disable this. HtmlEncode your results before you send them to the server. Disabling disabled some built in protections. Either way also use the Anti Cross site scripting libraries GetSafeHtmlFragment. By allowing html you can open yourself up to a cross site scripting attack.  See my talk here to understand the issues:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/DEV333

Answer (score -2):

In web.config find the following:

```
<pages validateRequest="true">
```

and change to:

```
<pages validateRequest="false">
```

Comment: I really worry about offering this as a solution to a single page - this disables it for the whole site.

Comment: Same here, I don't wanna disable it site-wide!